# Is there a way to see where Chunks meet?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to fix up a red stone system in the Spawn Chunk so it's always running no matter how far i go, however i'm concerned that when i start building it a part of the system will fall outside the chunk which could break the system, acting unpredictably because the chunk a part of the system is in doesn't update.

i am wondering, is there a way to see where Chunks meet so that i don't build this system between the 2 chunks?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Edit: Since  1.8, the best way to do this is to hit <kbd>F3</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>. This will display the chunk boundaries graphically in game. For other methods which involve coordinates, continue below.

In 1.7.x and below, if you turn on the debug display by hitting <kbd>F3</kbd>, you will see `x:`, `y:` and `z:` rows.

In the `x` and `z` rows, look at the end of each line - it shows `// c: number (number)` after each one. The first number is which chunk you are in, and the second is which block in that chunk, from 0 - 15.

In 1.8+, the debug screen displays the chunk coordinates differently. They are on their own line formatted as `x y z in Cx, Cy, Cz`, with `xyz` ranging from 0 to 15.

Hopefully that helps.

Note: for your specific situation, I'll add that the spawn chunks are actually a 16x16 chunk area around the [world spawn point](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn#World_Spawn), which can be exactly determined by throwing an item into the end portal from the end - the item will appear at the exact point of the world spawn. There are [other ways](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn_chunk#Finding_spawn_chunks) to find your spawn point, but if you've killed the dragon this is the easiest way.

Your redstone device should be able to occupy any chunks in that area without any problems, as they all stay loaded no matter what.

Comment: A more painfully complex [explanation of finding edges](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Chunks) is on the wiki, good job of making it simpler to understand!

Comment: The 1.8 snapshots feature a new debug screen. Chunk coordinates are displayed on a seperate line, formatted as `x y z in Cx, Cy, Cz`, with `xyz` ranging from 0 to 15. See http://s1.hubimg.com/u/8935698_f260.jpg

Answer (score 16):

If you have the Not Enough Items mod, you can press <kbd>F9</kbd> a couple times and a chunk grid will be displayed. It's nice as it's very graphical and easy to check if you are outside of the boundary.

However, you do need to have Forge and the NEI mod installed.

Screenshot I found on Imgur:
[image: Screenshot I found on Imgur]

If you hit <kbd>F9</kbd> again, you will get an alternate view of this which adds a grid in between the chunks, making them very visible.

You can also use the <kbd>F7</kbd> key to show where mobs spawn (if you want).

Answer (score 3):

Press F3 + G to show chunk boundaries.

Comment: I don't get why people are downvoting this, this is the easiest and fastest method as of 1.8.
And the approved answer only incorporated this solution in it a week after this answer was posted?

Comment: @Plagiatus it's possibly simply because this answer is fairly simple, compared to the other two, and while this was answered *before* the edit to the previous answers, without comparing those dates, it simply looks like this is copying them.